# pandas:how to get each customer probability with predict_proba

Tags: pandas

I am using xgboost with objective='binary:logistic' to calculate each customer probability if he/she will make the spend.
Using predic_proba in sklearn will print two probability for both 0 and 1,like:

```
[[0.56651809 0.43348191]  
 [0.15598162 0.84401838]  
 [0.86852502 0.13147498]]
```

how to insert each customer ID by pandas to get something like:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| ID |   prob_0   |   prob_1   |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | 0.56651809 | 0.43348191 |
|  2 | 0.15598162 | 0.84401838 |
|  3 | 0.86852502 | 0.13147498 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pandas DataFrame() in order to make your form.

```
    list_data = [[0.56651809, 0.43348191],[0.15598162, 0.84401838],[0.86852502, 0.13147498]]
    columns = ['prob_0', 'prob_1']
    index = [1, 2, 3]
    pd.DataFrame(data = list_data, columns = columns, index= index)
```